# C++ vector and list insertion

Tags: c++, performance, list, vector

Could anybody know why inserting an element into the middle of a list is faster
than inserting an element into the middle of a vector?

I prefer to use vector but am told to use list if I can.
Anybody can explains why?
And is it always recommended to use list over vector?

Comment: The nature of linked lists and arrays are essential for any programmer (in any language) to understand.  I would recommend getting a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) which will have the answer to this question (and much more).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I take the question verbatim, finding the middle of an array (std::vector) is a simple operation, you divide the length by two and then round up or down to get the index. Finding the middle of a doubly linked list (std::list) requires walking through all elements. Even if you know its size, you still need to walk over half of the elements. Therefore std::vector is faster than std::list, in other words one is O(1) while the other is O(n).

Inserting at a known position requires shuffing the adjacent elements for an array and just linking in another node for a doubly linked list, as others explained here. Therefore, std::list with O(1) is faster than std::vector with O(n).

Together, to insert in the exact middle, we have O(1) + O(n) for the array and O(n) + O(1) for the doubly linked list, making inserting in the middle O(n) for both container types. All this leaves out things like CPU caches and allocator speed though, it just compares the number of "simple" operations. In summary, you need to find out how you use the container. If you really insert/delete at random positions a lot, std::list might be better. If you only do so rarely and then only read the container, a std::vector might be better. If you only have ten elements, all the O(x) is probably worthless anyway and you should go with the one you like best.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting into the middle of the vector requires all the elements after the insertion point to be shuffled along to make space, potentially involving lots of copying.

The list is implemented as a linked list with each node occupying its own space in memory with references to neighboring nodes, so adding a new node just requires changing 2 references to point to the new node.

Depending on the data type you use, a vector may well perform much faster than a list. But the more complex the object is to copy, the worse a vector gets.

Answer (score 1):

Ulrich Eckhardt's answer is pretty good. I don't have enough reputation to add a comment so I will write an answer myself. Like Ulrich said the speed of insertion in the middle for both the list and the vector is O(n) in theory. In practice, modern CPUs have a thing called "prefetcher". it's pretty good at getting contiguous data. Since the vector is contiguous in memory, moving lots of elements is pretty fast because of the prefetcher. You need to be manipulating really, really big vectors in order for them to be slower in inserting than the list. For more details check this awesome blog post:

http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/data-locality.html

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, a vector is an array. So, its elements are stored in consecutive memory locations (i.e., one next to the other). The only exception is that a vector allows resizing during run-time, without causing data loss.

Now, to insert to a list, you identify the node, then create the new element (any where in memory), store the value and connect the pointers.

But in the case of the vector (array), you must physically move the elements from one cell to the other in order to create that space for a new elements. That physical movement is what causes the delay, particularly if many elements (i.e., data) needs to be moved. You are not physcially moving array elements. Rather, its their contents.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart in C++, `std::vector` is implemented using an  underlying dynamically allocated array.  The requirements of the standard make that the only possible implementation.